# How can I call my python function properly?

Tags: python

It's a simple code to calculate the volume of a sphere, but I am a noob. When I run the code, nothing is produced.

```
import math
def sphere_volume(radius):
  return (4/3)*math.pi*(radius**3)

  sphere_volume(10)
```

Comment: *How* do you "run the code"?  If you want something printed, you may need to call `print`.  Also, indentation matters in Python (which is a hint that your is wrong).

Comment: Your indentation, at least in the question, is wrong. The call to `sphere_volume` goes *after* the definition, not *in* the definition. You then still have to *do* something with the return value of the function. Only in the interactive interpreter does the value of an expression get automatically printed.

Comment: Due to the indentation the call of "sphere_volume" is in the function where it is never executed because the function isn't called.

Comment: Imagine being new at programming and trying to seek help and you guys just downvote him lol

Comment: Also note that as written, this function keeps calling itself and will end up raising a recursion error if it ever is called from somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Indentation is very important! The reason it isn't working is because you are calling your function from within the same one.

Also, consider adding a print statement to see output onto your terminal.

**Try This**

```
import math
def sphere_volume(radius):
  return (4/3)*math.pi*(radius**3)

sphere_volume(10) # removed indentation

# or print(sphere_volume)
```

Comment: @Sandeez - this answer seems correct to me. Could you either accept this (so we know the issue is resolved) or comment on what is missing?